# Laravel - Best Practices To Display Alert with Session & Test After

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

I have been developing online software for a month with Laravel.
When an action is performed (update, creation, etc.), I display an information message to the user.

**Like this in my controller :**

```
$request->session()->flash('alert', array(array('msg' => 'My first alert message', 'level' => 'success')));

$request->session()->push('alert', array('msg' => "My second message", 'level' => 'danger'));
```

**And in my view :**

```
@if(Session::has('alert'))
    @foreach(Session::get('alert') as $alert)
        <div class="alert alert-{{ $alert['level'] ?? 'info' }} alert-dismissible fade show">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            {{ $alert['msg'] }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

So far all right, I have often used this logic.

I happen to create the tests in my application (I use Pest PHP) and when I want to test a function in my controller that contains a session I get this error :

```
 • TestsControllersExchangesTest > it update exchange
   RuntimeException

  Session store not set on request.
```

Indeed in my test, I simulate a false request for the function (update for example) but when it comes time to flash a session message in the request it returns the error above.

**Can I insert a false session in the request (I can't find anyone who has succeeded on the Internet)?**

**Or should I change my alert system (which may not comply with best practices)?**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Facade metho Session :

```
Session::flash('alert', 'success|Notification text');
```

And for you blade alert :

```
@if(Session::has('alert'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ explode('|', Session::get('alert'))[0] ?? 'info' }} alert-dismissible fade show">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        {{ explode('|', Session::get('alert'))[1] }}
    </div>
@endif
```

**There is no longer any problem with the sessions in the tests.
You can simply mock your request without a session in it.**